# Powerpoint's eyedropper all of a sudden returning inverted (or, at any rate, wrong) colors

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I was trying to fill a shape with a color that exists elsewhere in my slide, so I used the indispensable Eyedropper tool, which normally works very well.

However, this now returns a color that is clearly not the one under the mouse cursor. In fact, it seems to be the inversion of that color. For instance, if I point to white, it returns black.

The screenshot below shows another example, where the color of the slide background is reported to be orange instead of blue.

[image]

I rebooted my PC and closed any programs that make special demands on the graphics card (e.g. flux), but the problem stays the same. It happens no matter what PPTX file is being worked on (including a blank one). The problem also isn't from the graphics card in general, as the eyedropper in other Windows graphics programs such as Photoshop work just fine.

Switching off the dark mode (by setting the Office theme to White), or restarting PowerPoint (or doing so in safe mode) doesn't change anything. What's also didn't work was to do an Office Repair, either the quick or the online version. Finally, I also suspected this might be linked to my laptop being hooked up via HDMI to an external monitor; but the problem exists in fact also when using the internal screen.

Using MS Office 365 (with auto updates), on a Windows 10 laptop with an Intel HD Graphics 620 graphics card. No further updates are available at this time for either Windows or MS Office (kept hoping subsequent updates would fix it but they haven't, as of October 2023).

EDIT APR '24: almost a year later, and this bug is exactly the same, despite numerous updates that Office is constantly asking to do. What an absolute embarrassment and disgrace this is, coming from one of the biggest software companies in the world, who you'd think has the resources to fix such problems!

Comment: It seems a bug. [Online you can find](https://pinetools.com/invert-color) a page to invert the color you obtain, or you can do some math by yourself, as hard as 255-R (or G or B). Eg  `255,143,63` --> `0,112,192`... Good luck.

Comment: Try in Programs and Features to repair Office via right-click.

Comment: tried that, didn't work.. will edit question to clarify

Comment: For a stronger action, you could uninstall Office and re-install. This should restore everything to the initial state. Question: Do you have installed any PowerPoint Add-ins? To verify if this is an add-in problem see [Open Office apps in safe mode on a Windows PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72).

Comment: Safe Mode is a good idea; it'll disable add-ins and will also handle more video calls in software rather than trusting the video driver's ability to handle things correctly. You might also download and try Pixie (http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php). If it works correctly where PPT doesn't, it's likely a PPT bug. If both of them give you inverted results, then it's likely a Windows or video driver issue.

Comment: Thanks! Used Instant [EYedropper](http://instant-eyedropper.com/), which probably is similar to Pixie. This continues to display the correct color under the eye dropper, whereas PowerPoint does not. So once again, the conclusion is that this is a PowerPoint bug, which unfortunately doesn't help in the short run.

Comment: True, but it also gives you a solid way to put the blame on PPT.  I'd use the Help | Feedback feature to report the bug (and be sure to mention that Eyedropper reports the correct colors.)  Using the built-in feedback will also make sure that the devs get needed info about your particular environment/PPT build etc.

Comment: will do, thanks again

Comment: This must have something to do with the dark mode theme...  You may have to go into word to switch this off.  Just a thought.  https://appuals.com/transparent-inverted-colors-ms-word/

Comment: You will see in my question that I already mentioned having tried to disable dark mode in Powerpoint, which in this case does nothing to help the problem. Word probably has its own interface settings, which I expect will have no impact on PowerPoint.

Comment: Have you tried [PowerPoint in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72)? Or reinstalling Office?

Comment: Starting PPT in safe mode leads to the same eyedropper problem. Reinstalling Office I didn't try yet, only the repair options mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I'm sure it's a PowerPoint bug. I didn't realize it was an inverted color, so thanks for pointing that out. Let's hope Microsoft fixes this soon.

In the meantime, ChatGPT wrote 3 macros for me to invert the colors after using the eyedropper, one for fill colors, and line colors, and text colors.

```vb
Sub InvertFillColor()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255 - shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB Mod 256, 255 - shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB \ 256 Mod 256, 255 - shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB \ 65536 Mod 256)
    Next shp
End Sub

Sub InvertLine()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255 - shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB Mod 256, 255 - shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB \ 256 Mod 256, 255 - shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB \ 65536 Mod 256)
    Next shp
End Sub

Sub InvertTextColor()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255 - shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB Mod 256, 255 - shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB \ 256 Mod 256, 255 - shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB \ 65536 Mod 256)
    Next shp
End Sub
```

1. Open Visual Basic (Alt+F11)
2. Insert a module (**Insert > Module**)
3. Paste in the code

If you want this to work after you close the file, you have to save the file as a Macro-Enabled file (.pptm).

Then assign each macro to a button on your Quick Access Toolbar. The macros will work for any file you have open, as long as the file with the macros in it is also open.
[image: Customize Quick Access Toolbar]

You can use the **Modify...** button to change the icon too. Here's what I'm using:
[image: Icons]

So use the eyedropper as normal, and immediately click the appropriate button and it will invert to the color you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful (albeit cumbersome) until - if ever - Microsoft fixes this bug!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue for months and just got lucky stumbling upon a solution:

- Click Windows Key + Plus symbol to open the Windows Magnifier app (or go to the search bar and search "Magnifier")
- Once the Magnifier app is open click the gear icon and then select "Go to settings" and unclick "Invert Colors"
- Close out of Magnifier and go back to power point and try using the eye dropper tool again

The above steps solved this problem for me. I'm not sure why this setting messed up the eyedropper even when the Magnifier app was not running, but it did, and when I turned it off the eye dropper worked again.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: thanks, I've been using something like this also, but if one is maintain a high workflow, this will definitely not do, for advanced users of PowerPoint. So hopefully Microsoft will up their game and fix this damn bug already (still there as of October 2023)